# iterate list of strings to get words count

Tags: r

I have a list of strings, like this:

```
index <- lst(string1="there is guy is there there", string2="have a have a ball a")
```

I want to get the descending words count for each string, so I did this function, which works fine on a single string:

```
get_wordcount <- function(text) {
  wordcount <- sort(table(unlist(strsplit(text, " "))), decreasing = TRUE)
  return(wordcount)
}
```

Then I did a for loop to iterate the function over all the strings of my list:

```
for (n in 1:length(index)) {
  assign(paste(names(index[n]), "wordcount", sep = "_"), get_wordcount(index[n]))
}
```

But it gives me this error: `Error in strsplit(text, " ") : non-character argument`
What am I doing wrong?

The desired outputs is:

```
> string1_wordcount <-   there                  is                      guy 
>                          3                     2                       1 
> 
> string2_wordcount <-     a                  have                     ball
>                          3                     2                        1
```

Comment: Why do you want to pollute the global environment? in scenarios like this consider to have results in a list/dataframe/table format. Notice that if you had 100000 strings, you will end up with 100000 objects in the environment. How will you deal with that? Better store everything in a list then you can always index them. or even better, have them in a tibble and you can group them etc... eg  even without using your function, you could do: `enframe(unlist(index))%>%  separate_rows(value)%>%  count(name, value)`

Answer (score 1):

The direct reason for the error is because the function uses `get_wordcount(index[n])` and the error should disappear if you use `get_wordcount(index[[n]])`.

`index[n]` gets a list containing a character string.

`index[[n]]` gets the n-th element of the list, which *is* a character string. And the function is designed to work with a character string.

In general, this approach of assigning the result to various object using a loop is not recommended in R. Generally using `lapply` to produce a list of results is preferred. It avoids filling your global environment with lots of objects and in some cases is much faster than assigning the results to many objects.

```
result <- lapply(index, get_wordcount)

result
# $string1
# 
# there    is   guy 
#     3     2     1 
# 
# $string2
# 
#    a have ball 
#    3    2    1 
#
```

The code above produces a single output `result` which is a list containing the 2 named elements you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
> index <- list(string1="there is guy is there there", string2="have a have a ball a")
> df <- as.data.frame(table(unlist(strsplit(as.character(index[[1]]), split = " "))))
> df
   Var1 Freq
1   guy    1
2    is    2
3 there    3
```

You just need to order the "Freq" column.

Answer (score 0):

Since we have a list, we can loop through the elements with `get_word_count`, then assign the list to the global env with `list2env`

```
library(purrr)
library(glue)

index %>%
    map(get_wordcount) %>%
    set_names(glue("{names(index)}_wordcount")) %>%
    list2env(envir = .GlobalEnv)

string1_wordcount

there    is   guy 
    3     2     1 

string2_wordcount

   a have ball 
   3    2    1
```

Comment: OP wants to assign the results to the global environment, so this doesn't exactly answer the question (though this was my first thought as well).

Comment: that is easy. Will edit accordingly. We can just use `list2env`. `assign` is a bit dangerous anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `unlist` your `text` argument. The way you've written it passes `text` as a `list` instead of `character vector`.

```r
index <- dplyr::lst(string1="there is guy is there there", string2="have a have a ball a")

get_wordcount <- function(text) {
  wordcount <- sort(table(unlist(strsplit(unlist(text), " "))), decreasing = TRUE)
  return(wordcount)
}

for (n in 1:length(index)) {
  assign(paste(names(index[n]), "wordcount", sep = "_"), get_wordcount(index[n]))
}

string1_wordcount
#> 
#> there    is   guy 
#>     3     2     1

string2_wordcount
#> 
#>    a have ball 
#>    3    2    1
```